# Join two SpatialPolygons keeping any polygons which overlap

Tags: r, spatial-database

The best way I can describe my problem is that I’m after a left inner join for two spatial objects???

As you can see below, I have two spatial objects: (1) State of California [in blue] and (2) Grid polygons [in red]. I am trying merge both objects but only for the grid polygons which "touch" the California object. E.g. keep the blue grid polygons and any red grid polygons which have blue in them.

I tried "raster::intersect", but this clips the coast/boundary.  Here's my code ....

```
library(rgdal)
library(raster)
library(rgeos)

# Download US shape information from data.gov
URL <- "http://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/GENZ2016/shp/cb_2016_us_state_500k.zip"
td <- tempdir()
setwd(td)
temp <- tempfile(fileext = ".zip")
download.file(URL, temp)
unzip(temp)

# Get US shape file and filter states for just California
us_states <- raster::shapefile("cb_2016_us_state_500k.shp")
ca <- subset(us_states, STUSPS == "CA")

# Create a grid  
grid <- raster(extent(ca))
res(grid) <- c(1)
proj4string(grid) <- proj4string(ca)
gridpolygon <- rasterToPolygons(grid)

# Merge objects together
merged <- raster::intersect(ca, gridpolygon)

plot(gridpolygon, add=TRUE, col='red')
plot(merged, add=TRUE, col='blue')  # This clips the grids
```

[image: California with grid polygons]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your not quite ready to take the plunge into `sf`, look into `rgeos::gIntersects`. It will return a boolean vector that you can use to subset your polygons dataframe. It does not clip.

Comment: Its a one-liner: `gridpolygon2 = gridpolygon[gIntersects(gridpolygon, ca, byid=TRUE)[1,],]` (after `library(rgeos)`)

Answer (score 1):

You should get yourself the sf and tidyverse packages:

```
library(sf)
library(tidyverse)

cali_sf <- st_as_sf(ca)
grid_sf <- st_as_sf(gridpolygon)

# select all overlapping tiles
cal_grid <- st_intersects(grid_sf, cali_sf, sparse = F) %>%
  cbind(grid_sf, 'keep' = .) %>%
  filter(keep == TRUE)

# or, trimmed to state bdy
cal_grid_neat <- st_intersection(grid_sf, cali_sf)
```

Note the warnings, you should really be working in a projected crs when doing geometric overlay operations. st_transform and st_crs will help once you have identified an appropriate system.

Comment: Those pipes and cbinds and filters are a long-winded way of doing: `cal_grid <- grid_sf[st_intersects(grid_sf, cali_sf, sparse = FALSE),]` which doesn't require loading in any of the tidyverse (which is only being used to run `filter` here anyway) and doesn't leave a redundant `keep` column in the data. Not very tidy.

Comment: Very efficient. Stepping through the process line by line can be helpful when learning though, and `select(-keep)` is a simple addition.

Comment: Until one day you are analysing data on castles, and you have a "keep" column that is a flag for whether the castle had a keep or not, and then suddenly you have a weird bug. Contrived, yes, but general good practice is to not pollute data frames like this, even if you try and clear up afterwards!